# sql fix negative values

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I would like to produce the following result:

```
Table:[0050 Fix No Hit].[Fix_No_Hit]
Policy Number:     Insurance Score:   Insurance Score Factor:
100                  500                     2.13
101                  720                     1.47
102                  815                     1.00
103                  900                     0.69
```

Using the rules below:

```
Table: Tier_InsuranceScore
Insurance Score Chart:                      Factor:                 
649 or below                           2.13
(i assume insurance score has to be greater than 0) 
650 to 699                             1.86
700 to 799                             1.47
800 to 849                             1.00
850 to 899                             0.82
900 or above                           0.69
```

This is what I have so far:

```
    SELECT HWData.[Policy Number], [0050 Fix No Hit].[Fix_No_Hit], 
       iif([0050 Fix No Hit].[Fix_No_Hit] < 0, "Invalid",
       iif([0050 Fix No Hit].[Fix_No_Hit] <= 649, 2.13,
       iif([0050 Fix No Hit].[Fix_No_Hit] <= 699, 1.86, 
       iif([0050 Fix No Hit].[Fix_No_Hit] <= 799, 1.47, 
       iif([0050 Fix No Hit].[Fix_No_Hit] <= 849, 1.00, 
       iif([0050 Fix No Hit].[Fix_No_Hit] <= 899, 0.82, 
       iif([0050 Fix No Hit].[Fix_No_Hit] >= 900, 0.69, 0)))))) AS [Insurance Score Factor]
    FROM [0050 Fix No Hit];
```

I can not fix the negative values. I want to have the insurance score to be at least 0, so if I have a -5 as my insurance score, I will get an error message like invalid or something.

Comment: Do you want to: prevent negative values entering the database? allow negative number but handle their display in a special way? something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a question about the negative insurance scores. Is this something you can prevent from coming into your database/table? With what you are saying, an insurance score needs to be positive. I think that logic should be put in as a constraint on the column to ensure data integrity on `INSERT` or `UPDATE` of the records.

If you are unable to do that, are you able to set the `Insurance Score Factor` to 0 (or -1, or other identifying value) and check for that in your application code, and throw the appropriate error then?

Another option would be to add:

```
WHERE [0050 Fix No Hit].[Fix_No_Hit] > 0
```

to ensure you are only bringing back policies with a valid insurance score. You could also run a second query / create a report to check for the invalid policies, and handle them manually to put in a valid insurance score.